# Posting to Django server from java applet

Tags: java, python, django, client-side

I have to send some string from Java applet(invoked from template) to my django server, what would implementation of java applet part might look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a link to code snippet,which helps you in sending http requests to server

http://www.aviransplace.com/2008/01/08/make-http-post-or-get-request-from-java/